# Setting size() of a scalar

Tags: fortran

In some legacy code, I found the following line

```
size(k)=N
```

What (if anything) does this do?  As far as I know, it does not make sense to set `size(thing)` to a value in Fortran.

Furthermore, `k` is implicitly defined as a scalar `integer` (i.e. there it is not declared in the source file), it is used as a loop counter.  `N` is also `integer`, it is read from a file.

If I surround the statement with debug prints,

```
write(0,*) size(kkk), N, kkk
size(kkk)=N
write(0,*) size(kkk), N, kkk
```

I get output like the following:

```
-619273800         601           1
       601         601           1
     11007         595           2
       595         595           2
-619273800         620           3
       620         620           3
     11007         595           4
       595         595           4
         0         617           5
       617         617           5
         0         618           6
       618         618           6
         0         612           7
       612         612           7
```

So it seems like *something* is being set, but I do not know what.  Also, I do not think that this is leading to any problems (in fact, I do not think it really does anything), I am just curious.

Comment: `size(k)=N` makes perfect sense when `size` is an array variable.  Can you find a declaration for it somewhere?

Comment: @francescalus you are absolutely right!  `size(:)` was declared in a module imported in my subroutine.  My editor highlights it as a keyword, and I do not even consider it might be a variable.  I think I want to rename that variable though … Is it even possible to refer to the intrinsic procedure `size()` where the variable `size` is in scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SIZE` is the name of an intrinsic function which returns the size of an array.  In that context, you are correct that having it on the left-hand size of an assignment expression makes no sense.  And it's not allowed.

However, Fortran allows you to declare variables (and functions, etc.) with the same name as an intrinsic function.  When this happens, reference to the name is to the variable and not the function.  You can read about this in Fortran 2008's 16.3.1 which talks about *local identifiers*.  In particular, it notes

> An intrinsic procedure is inaccessible by its own name in a scoping unit that uses the same name as a local identifier of class (1) for a different entity.

Class (1) covers named variables.

As you say the array variable `size` comes from module use association, you can rename it to something else

```
use module_with_size, not_intrinsic_size => size
```

and refer to it by its new name from there on, leaving `size` to refer to the intrinsic function.

<sup>Having `size(k)=N` also makes sense for `size` a function when that is a statement function declaration.</sup>